# Latent Variables and Density e.g. in Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, conditional-probability, machine-learning, bayesian

Suppose we have a gaussian mixture 
$$ p(x) = \sum_k \pi_k \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_k, \Sigma_k) $$
and we want to do inference on it. A common way is to introduce a categorical latent variable $z$ with $p(z_k =1) = \pi_k$. Then one writes 
$$ p(x|z) = \prod_{k=1}^K \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_k, \Sigma_k)^{z_k}$$
and 
$$ p(x,z) = p(x|z)p(z). $$

I don't quite understand this last part. As I understand it $p(x)$ and $p(x|z)$ are *probability densities* (with respect to the lebesgue measure). But $p(z)$ is a *probability measure*, which doesn't even allow a lebesgue density. So how is the product between them to be understood?

Answer (score 1):

Your specification of the conditional distribution $p(x|z)$ is slightly incorrect. It should read:

$$ p(x|z) = \prod_{k=1}^K \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_k, \Sigma_k)^{I(z = k)}$$

so then you can see that,

$$ p(x) = \sum_k p(x,z) = \sum_k p(x|z)p(z) = \sum_k P(Z=k) \prod_{k'} \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_{k'}, \Sigma_{k'})^{I(z = k)} = \sum_k \pi_k \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_k, \Sigma_k).$$

Comment: I was thinking of a one-hot encoding of $z$, so I think the representations are equal. I understand that we get $p(x)$ by marginalizing $p(x,z)$. But what I don't understand, is what kind of object $p(x,z)$ acutally is. It's not a lebesgue-density as $z$ is categorical, but it can't be a probability measure either because $x$ is continuous.

Comment: It’s perfectly acceptable to define probability spaces without using the Lebesgue measure. For instance, the counting measure. If you want to get real technical about it, you’re defining a probability space on the product space of of the real numbers and some set with K elements in it. You’re totally allowed to define a measure on elements of a sigma algebra of that space.

Comment: Yes, I aggree that we can take the product measure of $x$ and $z$. This is however not given by $p(x,z)$ as defined above (note that $p$ is not a measure, as it doesn't take sets as input). In fact $p(x,z)$ seems to be a rather weird object, which for every fixed $z$ gives a density $p(\cdot, z)$. It just seems odd to me that we treat it like $x$ and $z$ have a joint density, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: It’s not a density, no, it’s a distribution (technically the distribution is just a function that maps measurable spaces to a real number between 0 and 1, not the function we think of as the density/mass function). It’s actually a joint distribution defined by a conditional distribution and a marginal distribution. You can define them in either order x given z and z or z given x and x. I highly recommend you checkout this [link](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/conditional_probability_theory.html) since you seem to be hung up on a misunderstanding of the formal definitions.

Comment: Both that link and the preceding article, Probability Theory for Scientists and Engineers, are really excellent!

Comment: Thanks. But note that $p(x, z)$ doesn't necessarily map to $[0, 1]$, so it's not a distribution by your definition.

Comment: Again, you're confusing the definition of a probability density function with the actual distribution. The density function is not constrained to be between [0, 1]. The actual function that maps a measurable set to the measure associated with that set is constrained. The density helps us define this function. This is just like how the density doesn't define how much mass an object has in physics unless you know the volume as well. The density function helps us assign probability mass to a certain volume, i.e. $P([0, x]) = \int_0^x f(x) dx.$

Comment: Honestly, I think you're confused. I'm perfectly fine with the terms. $p(x,z)$ is not a density function as the joint measure of $x$ and $z$ does not have a density (which you aggreed upon). However in your last comment you seem to suggest that $p(x,z)$ is a density? On the other hand it's easy to see that $p(x, z)$ doesn't necessarily map to $[0, 1]$, so it's not a mass function. The only way to accurately describe the joint distribution of $x$ and $z$ is by its measure. Using the object $p(x,z)$ seems to be a workaround which somehow works but is not mathematically accurate.